# How to go about finding the second independent linear series solution through reduction of order (infinite series diff. eq)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, differential, reduction-of-order-ode

$x^2y[''] + 2y['] +2[y] = 0$

irregular singular point $x=0$

How would I go about the reduction process to find $y2(x)$ (the second linearly independent solution)? This is a textbook solution and no one online has attempted to find the second linear independent solution or even explain how to to go about the process either.

For reference,
I already got $y1(x)$ which

$y1(x)=1+x+(1/2)x^2 + ...$

and the problem only requires finding the first three nonzero terms of the series expansion

Thank you

Comment: Soutions for differential equations involving irregular singular points involve products of the exponential function with a Frobenius series. If I find some time I can type up a break down of this problem...

Comment: For $x=0$, you'd have $2y'(0)+2y(0)=0$, and your $y1(x)$ certainly *doesn't* satisfy that. And in general: what makes you believe that both linearly independent solutions are regular at $x=0$?